# Get id from class selector without click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the `id` from a class selector without clicking.

```
var type_selected = '' ;
$('.type_selected').attr();
type_selected = (this.id);
```

Comment: Please fully explain what you want to do.  *Hint: get id from class selector without click* does not explain it.  **Fully** explain.

Comment: @KobyDouek there is no `this` reference to the element without an event handler.

Comment: var type_selected = '' ;
type_selected = $('.type_selected').attr('id');

Comment: Are there multiple `.type_selected` elements? If so, how do you know which `id` to retrieve? I'd also strongly suggest you read the jquery documentation as you have some fairly obvious logic issues: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @AhmedItos that should work. Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: undefined in alert

Comment: Are you running your code in a jQuery document.ready event handler? It sounds like you may be trying to run the code before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: no i run it in function

Comment: Then a more complete sample of your code would really help us to diagnose the issue. Could you please edit the question to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. This will return an array of all elements with that class;

```js
var type_selected = [];
$('.type_selected').each(function(){
    type_selected.push($(this).attr("id"));
});

console.log(type_selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="type_selected" id="id1">This is a test<p>
<p class="type_selected" id="id2">This is a test 2<p>
<p class="type_selected" id="id3">This is a test<p>
```

Comment: Why downvote???

Comment: Didn't DV, but it was exactly for the same reason another identical answer was deleted - _"What if there's more than one element with that class name?"_, but now with your edit it is a correct answer so +1

Comment: whats wrong with `this.id`? everything don't have to be done with jquery... map instead of each loop would also have been better